# Editing record within list, with dynamically defining children properties with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With VueJS, I am trying to create a generic component that would work with different types of records.

For instance, let's say I have user records:

```
var users = [
  { UserID: 1, username: "pan",email:"peter.pan@neverland.com" },
  { UserID: 2, username: "john",email:"john.doe@somewhere.com" }
];
```

And group records

```
var groups = [
    { GroupId: 1, groupName: "Users", description: "Lorem ipsum ..." },
    { GroupId: 2, groupName: "Admins", description: "Some people with super powers" }
];
```

I want to create a Vue component to edit those records, so it can be defined as such:

```
<record-editor v-bind:record="user[0]" title="Edit user">
  <text-editor label="User name" property="username"></text-editor>
  <text-editor label="Email" property="email"></text-editor>
</record-editor>

<!-- For the binding syntax, I am not sure what should 
     I use to bind to a record in the lists shown before -->

<record-editor v-bind:record="groups[0]" title="Edit group"> 
  <text-editor label="groupName" property="groupName"></text-editor>
  <text-editor label="Description" property="description"></text-editor>
</record-editor>
```

Right now, what I have is:

```
(function() {
    var textEditor = Vue.component('text-editor', {
        template: "#text-editor",
        props: ['label', 'property']
    });

    var recordEditor= Vue.component('record-editor', {
        template: '#model-editor',
        props: ['title', 'record']
    });

    var vue = new Vue({
      el:"#someContainer",
      data: {
        users : users,
        groups: groups
      }
    })
}())

<template id="text-editor">
    <div>
        <label v-bind:for="property">{{label}}</label>

        <!-- need help figuring what to put in v-bind:value -->
        <input type="text" v-bind:name="property" 
                           v-bind:id="property"
                           v-bind:value="">
    </div>
</template>

<template id="record-editor">
    <div>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <form>
            <slot></slot>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

So basically, what I am missing is how to bin to the elements in the list to edit them.

And how can I dynamically define properties for the sub components (text-editor).

Comment: Are you aware you're coding `text-editor` as a [slot](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot) rather than a child of `record-editor`?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the difference, a child of record-editor would be passed to the components options in record editor's constructor, while building it as a slot allows it to be put anywhere ?

Comment: If the `<text-editor>` tags appeared in the *template* of `record-editor`, it would be a child. Here, they appear between the `<record-editor>` tags, so they are in the outer scope by default (the scope is changed by using a scoped slot as per Bert's answer).

Comment: Ok, then, this is how I want it to be, so the record-editor can be used for different types of records, as well as different types of editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) and `v-model`. Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

var users = [
  { UserID: 1, username: "pan",email:"peter.pan@neverland.com" },
  { UserID: 2, username: "john",email:"john.doe@somewhere.com" }
];

var groups = [
    { GroupId: 1, groupName: "Users", description: "Lorem ipsum ..." },
    { GroupId: 2, groupName: "Admins", description: "Some people with super powers" }
];

var textEditor = Vue.component('text-editor', {
  template: "#text-editor",
  props: ['label', 'value'],
  computed:{
    property:{
      get(){ return this.value},
      set(v){this.$emit("input", v)}
    }
  }
});

var recordEditor= Vue.component('record-editor', {
  template: '#record-editor',
  props: ['title', 'record']
});

var vue = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    users : users,
    groups: groups
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <record-editor v-bind:record="users[0]" title="Edit user">
    <template scope="{record}">
    <text-editor label="User name" v-model="record.username"></text-editor>
    <text-editor label="Email" v-model="record.email"></text-editor>
  </template>
  </record-editor>
  {{users}}
</div>

<template id="text-editor">
    <div>
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="property">
    </div>
</template>

<template id="record-editor">
    <div>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <form>
            <slot :record="record"></slot>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

I removed the label and id binding you were doing in the text editor primarily because an email address is an invalid id for an input element. Essentially I updated your `text-editor` to work with `v-model` which will substitute for your `property` binding. A scoped slot is required because you are defining the model you want to edit on the `record-editor`. A scoped slot allows you to pass data from the enclosing scope to the contained components.